# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable | discord.py

Tags: python, discord

**Сам код:**

```
connection=sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот успешно подключен к серверу!')
    

    await client.change_presence( status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('Sublime (пишет код)') )
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            name TEXT,
            id INT,
            cash BIGINT,
            lvl INT
        )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 1)")
                

            else:
                pass
    connection.commit()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()

    else:
        pass

@client.command( pass_context = True)
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
# 94 строчка,в которой вроде ошибка, строкой ниже
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f"""баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
        description = f"""баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
```

**Ошибка:**
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

---

*Уже очень долго не могу понять в чем проблема. Списывал в точь точь с гайдов, пробовал копипастить у других.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` означает, что вы пробуете выполнить операцию `[]` для `None`.

В вашем случае запрос `SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}` очевидно не нашел пользователя и `.fetchone()` возвращает `None`.